# Excel - Linking a cell to another when the source changes

Tags: excel

I have a table with a SQL database script for a source. Let's say the colored cells below are the result. Is it possible to write comments in columns D/E that will be linked to the user ID from column A, so when the source changes (i.e. I refresh the table) those comments will find their ID they were written for and move there?

Or if you have some better ideas on how to do something similar. I want to create something like a register for some coworkers. The data inside is not cumulative, some users may appear and then disappear on different days. The user ID however will always be the same. The coworkers need to be able to write some comments so they know the user has already been checked and ignore him. So I need some way for the comments to stick to the specific user.

[image]

Comment: Use a different table for the User ID and comments and then use a formula (XLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH, etc) to populate columns D and E.

Answer (score 0):

If your comments are unique to User ID, then create separate table.
Method 1: Use Formulas as "BigBen" suggested.
Method 2: Load the "comments" table into Data Model, apply Merge or build a relationship via Power Query/Pivot. Extract the Report, Output will produce the data with the comments.